# Unit Test is Providing 0% Coverage for Apex Trigger - Test class for trigger

Tags: trigger, unit-test

```
trigger Splittrigger_newclass on Indexing__c (before delete,after insert) {
list<C_Voyage__c> lstvoyage=new list<C_Voyage__c>();
    list<string> q = new list<string>();
    list<string> p = new list<string>();

       //To store parent ids
    list<id> IndIds=new list<id>();
    for(Indexing__c Ind:trigger.old)
    {
        IndIds.add(Ind.id);
        system.debug('inids>>>'+IndIds);
    }  
    //Collecting all child records related to Parent records
    list<C_Voyage__c> listVoyage=[select id,main_case_id__c from C_Voyage__c where Indexing__c in :IndIds];
    system.debug('listVoyage'+listVoyage.size());
    //deleting child records
    delete listVoyage;

    for(Indexing__c y:trigger.new)
    {
        system.debug('INdex>>>>>'+y);
        if(y.Voyage_Created_Ref__c !=null)
        {
    p=y.Voyage_Created_Ref__c.split(',');
    for (Integer i = 0; i < p.size();i++) {
        C_Voyage__c tst = new C_Voyage__c();
        tst.Voyage_Ref__c = p[i];
        tst.Voyage_Type__c = 'Created';
        tst.Indexing__c= y.Id;
        tst.main_case_id__c= y.Case_Indexing_Ref__c;
        lstvoyage.add(tst);
        system.debug('listofvoyage>>>>>'+lstvoyage);
    }
   upsert lstvoyage;
     if(y.Voyage_Amended_Ref__c !=null)
    {

    q=y.Voyage_Amended_Ref__c.split(',');

    for (Integer j = 0; j < q.size();j++) {
        C_Voyage__c atst = new C_Voyage__c();
        atst.Voyage_Ref__c = q[j];
        atst.Voyage_Type__c = 'Amended';
        atst.Indexing__c= y.Id;
        atst.main_case_id__c= y.Case_Indexing_Ref__c;
        lstvoyage.add(atst);
    }

   upsert lstvoyage;
    }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Please provide code what you have tried, we will help on that.

Comment: Try two weeks things 1) clear test coverage or/and 2) edit and save the original apex class.

Comment: We can't help you without seeing your test class.